# Sort 2d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2d matrix, the first column is numeric, second is string and third is string, I want to sort by the first column. Here is my code used to create the loop.

Thanks

```
for i = 1:length(queries)
    for j = 1:length(textures)
        results{i * j, 1} = HI(queries{i, 2}, textures{j, 2});
        results{i * j, 2} = textures{j, 3};
        results{i * j, 3} = queries{i, 3};
    end

    results = sort(results, 1);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
c = {0.608920898437500  'D1.gif'    'D106.gif'
     0.803334960937500  'D1.gif'    'D109.gif'
     0.831228027343750  'D1.gif'    'D26.gif'}; %// example data
cSorted = sortrows(c,1); %// sort rows according to first column
```

The result is

```
cSorted = 
    [0.6089]    'D1.gif'    'D106.gif'
    [0.8033]    'D1.gif'    'D109.gif'
    [0.8312]    'D1.gif'    'D26.gif'
```

Comment: Thanks, however i get the error

Error using char
Cell elements must be character arrays.

Error in sortrows>sort_cell_back_to_front
(line 136)
            tmp = char(x(ndx,k));

Error in sortrows (line 88)
        ndx = sort_cell_back_to_front(x_sub,
        col);

Error in main (line 68)
    results = sortrows(results);

Comment: The data is of type double, could this be causing the error?

Comment: @NickPocock If your cell contents are strings you shouldn't get that error. See my example. Perhaps your cell contents are not strings?

Comment: @NickPocock No, double is not a problem. Maybe post a minimal example of your `results` array (two or three rows)